# When and when not to use step function when Fourier transforming real-timed signals

Tags: fourier-transform

Take the following 2 functions: (i) right-sided exponential decay. (ii) right-sided ramp.

Let's say I want to calculate the Fourier transforms of each of them. The reason for this is to calculate the energy in frequencies above w1, as a fraction of the energy in frequencies above w2, where w1>w2.

Being very unsure of myself, I go through the first 10 pages of google searches. I find that for (i), I do not need to include the implicit step response at t=0, whereas for (ii) I do need to include the implicit step response at t=0.

To complicate matters, I find that one incorrect way of proceeding with (ii) is to take a right-sided exponential decay and take the limit in the exponent coefficient tending to zero.......this is acknowledge to be incorrect as it misses the step at t=0, yet the same people who point this out do not also say that the general case of right-sided exponential decays is also wrong, for exactly the same reason.

Help!

Comment: PS I am aware that I could avoid the issue with using a Laplace transform, but I do not think I can interpret the integrated square modulus of a Laplace transform as energy. Someone please tell me that I am wrong, but I dont think I am.

Comment: OK - done it. You are supposed to include the implicit step response even with exponential decay, but it drops out in the maths. All sorted.

Comment: Actually no, I was wrong. It doesnt drop out in the maths. Now I am confused as I was in the first place.